# res.Text = "\n\n" + Regex.Split("THE THEVA RESIDENCY 0|Boutique Hotels 1|","|")[1];Regex doing terrible

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
res.Text = "\n\n" + Regex.Split("THE THEVA RESIDENCY 0|Boutique Hotels 1|","|")[1];
```

This gives me only the first string of the First items "T"...

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to split the string with `|` as the delimiter. To do this use `[|]`. Change the regex pattern parameter from `"|"` to `"[|]"`.

```
res.Text = "\n\n" + Regex.Split("THE THEVA RESIDENCY 0|Boutique Hotels 1|","[|]")[1];
```

The reason why `|` did not work because on its own it is a Alternation Construct. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#alternation_constructs

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to extract the substring "Boutique Hotels 1" then perhaps you want

```
res.Text = "\n\n" + "THE THEVA RESIDENCY 0|Boutique Hotels 1|".Split('|')[1];
```

Comment: And if you wanted "THE THEVA RESIDENCY 0" then change the `[1]` to a `[0]`